# Vue.js : Append an existing div element to another or get existing html content in data

Tags: vue.js, innerhtml

I'm new to `Vue.js`. I already have a div content (eg. `<div class="test1">text text text etc. </div>`). I'm trying **to move that div into another div**. I know how to do it in jQuery:

```
$(".test1").appendTo(".test2")
```

But how to do that in Vue.js?
I also tried to store data this way:

```
const App = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      page_footer_code: (.test).innerHtml,
}
....
```

but it is not correct code. Is there anything similar like this?

Comment: Vue.js uses in internal representation of your DOM called the "Virtual DOM". You should not manually manipulate the DOM as this will cause the virtual and actual DOM to go out of sync which will create all kinds of side effects. You can read [this article](https://codeburst.io/guide-to-vue-js-for-jquery-developers-6e16e9ae1505) first to learn more about how to move to Vue.js from a jQuery background.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component and nest it inside another one using [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots)

here is an example :

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false


Vue.component('test1',{
 template : '<div class="test1">' +
              'some content inside test 1' +
               '<slot></slot>' +
            '</div>'
})

Vue.component('test2',{
 template : '<div class="test2">text text text etc.</div>'
})


new Vue({
 el :'#app',
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<test1>
    <test2></test2>
</test1>
</div>
```

Comment: The question was not about nesting components but the OP is asking how to directly manipulate DOM elements like he / she used to do it with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I will make that div element into a component,
and put it below where you need to show it (in multiple places).
Then use a variable to control the display (v-show / v-if).
You better not trying to manipulate the DOM with Vue.

Answer (score 0):

@andypotato, yes you are right, I should not manipulate manually.
I decided to use that `appendTo` as jQuery in mount() & continue other things with Vue.js.

Thanks everyone for the help.